# ALTER TYPE command in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I am new to Cassandra and I am using version 3.11.

I have below UDT type and I am trying to write ALTER Query to change. I am able to write separate command for RENAME, ADD but I want to have all in one query.  Could I get help to have in one query.

```
create type if not exists payment_types (
      billing_type int,
      payer_id text
);
```

ALTER TYPE payment_types to have following fields

```
          billing_type text,
          billing_id text,
          biller_name text,
          payer_name text
```

Also when I was executing i am getting

```
 Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Altering of types is not allowed"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using cassandra 3.11 version.

Here is details:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlAlterTable.html

There are some specifications to alter data types:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#cql_data_types_c__cql_data_type_compatibility

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlAlterType.html  Here it has steps for ALTER for different ones like add, rename, alter field. But I am trying for combining all in one statement.

Comment: You are trying to ADD AND RENAME AND ALTER DATA TYPE in one statement? Did you try batchStatement to apply all ALTER operation in one batch?